# How to make a while-statment print out every 3rd number?

Tags: java, while-loop

How to make a while-statment print out every 3rd number?

I know that this will print out ever number from 0 to 100:

```
package WhileStatement;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class WhileStatementOne {

        //See the Scanner packet for more info.
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args){
        countNumber();
    }
        //We can now call ' countNumber ' at any time in this code.
    private static void countNumber(){
        // This is the whilestatement.
        int i = 0;
        while(i <=100){
            System.out.println(i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

But how can I make it print out this:

```
3
6
9
12
15
etc...
```

Comment: Start on `i=3` and add 3 each time round?

Comment: `System.out.println(i*3)`

Comment: @Ingo Then you should `while(i <=33)`

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun Yes, or `(i*3 <= 100)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with:

```
int i = 1;
while (i++ <= 100){
    if ( i % 3 == 0 ) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

or:

```
int i = 3;
while (i <= 100){
    System.out.println(i);
    i += 3;
}
```

or even:

```
for (int i : new Range(3,100,3)) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun The last one just shows that the problem can be solved in many ways ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Increase by 3

```
private static void countNumber(){
    // This is the whilestatement.
    int i = 3;
    while(i <=100){
        System.out.println(i);
        i+=3;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    int i = 3;
    while(i <=100){
        System.out.println(i);
        i += 3;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) with [`IntStream`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) :

```
IntStream.iterate(3, x -> x + 3).limit(100/3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output :

```
3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60 63 66 69 72 75 78 81 84 87 90 93 96 99
```

Answer (score 1):

This loop is not good. But without changing your flow. Just add a condition to statify what u want.

```
int i = 0;
    while (i <= 100) {
        if (i != 0 && i % 3 == 0)
            System.out.println(i);
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 3; i <= 100; i+=3)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=3; i < 100; i = i + 3) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```